# Latest block hash does not work on mainnet

Tags: blockhash

I have a program launched onto mainnet, but I cannot connect to it. Every time I try, I get a `Blockhash not found` error. I have confirmed my connection works on devnet without an issue. I have tried using the solana RPC, Serum, and a private syndica RPC node, but all of them error. I have tried setting my connection commitment to `finalized`, and various configurations for the retry options, and these do not help. Additionally, I confirmed the `lastValidBlockHeight` is greater than the current block height on mainnet when trying to send a transaction. I even tried using an online example outlined here (with updating deprecated functions): https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/461#issuecomment-1174070167. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: We can answer this question better if you share a code block with the last command or transaction you sent before getting the `Blockhash not found` error.  Often that specific error means you are sending a transaction to an RPC directly instead of using the `@solana/web3js` wrapper - this is perfectly fine, but helper methods in web3js will fetch and set a recent blockhash as you submit transactions. When sending via the RPC API, ensure you are fetching and setting a recent mainnet blockhash on your transaction.